# One of the slick sliders not downloaded successful when site start first

Tags: slick.js

I have 2 sliders on the page. One of them load always, and second don't load first. After restart page, it's work. But people who come to website first can see this bug. Please help to solve the problem. It's my [site](http://rb-clipmaking.ru/).

I'm ask this question on [ru.stackoverflow](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/891005/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b3%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b7%d0%ba%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-slick) but I didn't get the answer.
I tried solutions from [Slick Slider Width 0 On Initial Page Load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48254835/slick-slider-width-0-on-initial-page-load), but I didn't see result.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was with parent `div` of slick slider had `dispaly:flex`
Don't change default display of slick. It's may be problem